# PivotCache.Create unable to handle large Range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

This run ok:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
With tgtBook.Sheets("Data")
    Set pc = tgtBook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("A1:B5"), Version:=Excel.xlPivotTableVersion14) ' Range("myMthdata"))
End With
```

The throws a Run-time error '13' Type mismatch:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
With tgtBook.Sheets("Data")
    Set pc = tgtBook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("A1:B500000"), Version:=Excel.xlPivotTableVersion14) ' Range("myMthdata"))
End With
```

The only difference is the number of rows in the SourceData. Is this a bug or is there a logical reason behind this seeming inconsistency?

---

**EDIT**

On further investigation it seems like B65536 will work whereas anything greater will bug. This is the max number of rows in the old version of Excel not `excel-2010`. Feels like a bug.

Anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it works better if you use an R1C1 style reference rather than a Range object or an A1 style string:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
    Set pc = tgtBook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Data!R1C1:R500000C2", Version:=Excel.xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

Comment: +1 Excellent - the perfect workaround for what effectively is a bug in the software.