# Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument when defining Pivot Cache using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am finding this issue "Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument" when defining the PivotCache on my code. The Excel I am using is 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 32 bit. VBA 7.

```
'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Sort Age of Case
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("M" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("M3:M" & LastRow), _
   Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "US MASTER"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set PSheet = Worksheets("US MASTER")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("US Master Macro")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'
'Pivot Table 1
'

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("B3"), TableName:="Total Backlog")
```

Comment: I don't see where you have `Set PRange...` Did you just not include that line in this question? Also - not related to the error you're getting, but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel) suggests using a `String` reference, not `Range` object, for `SourceData`. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hey @BigBen, I reran the code as using PRange and it still doesnt work. `'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)'
'Pivot Table 1
'

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("B3"), _
TableName:="Total Backlog")` And I get the following error: Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Comment: The Type Mismatch error is what the article I referenced above mentioned. I think you should follow its recommendation, instead of using `PRange`.

Comment: @BigBen when I set PRange as a string it's giving me a Compile error:Object required when I define the PRange. I guess I need help knowing how to change the script.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range) is helpful. In your case, should be something like `SourceData:="'US Master Macro'!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C" & lastCol`. That's the point the article raises - not using a `Range` Object, but a `String` reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a `PivotCache`, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel) recommends using a `String` reference to specify the workbook, worksheet and cell range for `SourceData`, instead of passing a `Range` object.

Instead of using `PRange` (which you've forgotten to `Set` here), you can use R1C1 notation, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range) suggests.

```
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

... SourceData:="'US Master Macro'!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C" & LastCol
```

Comment: This drove me crazy for hours!!!! I was trying to create a table (not a pivot table). I made a range (with myworkbook.sheets(1) .... myrange = .Range(blah) .... ) then passed it and got this error. But passing the range call directly works fine (instead of assigning it to a variable and passing that). Incredible! Why would this even matter?

Comment: @S.Melted - not sure exactly what you were trying to do... Almost sounds like a different issue, if you're dealing with a table (`ListObject`) and not a pivot table.

Comment: Yes, it was different. However, your answer to this question is what I needed to get me there. I can't for the life of me understand why setting a variable equal to a range [e.g. myRange = myworkbook.sheets(1).Range("A1:C2")] and then passing that variable to ListObjects.Add  fails, but placing that same snippet directly into the ListObjects.Add call works....??? I wanted to comment to help a few lost souls who think like me find and parse this thread easier.

Comment: Did you forget the `Set`, i.e. `Set myRange = ....`? @S.Melted

Comment: Apparently yes. (-_-)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is encountering a similar problem and the above answer does not solve, if you are using Slicers which are connected to various pivots (all of which come from the same data source) then the ChangePivotCache will not work unless you disconnect the pivots from the slicer first. 
A few days of searching through questions/answers and finally came across the problem!