# VBA Pivot Table; Error '1004' Refrence is not valid

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am creating a sheet that grabs data from another workbook and creates a pivot table based off the data.The error im running into is when I try to create the pivot table error '1004' Breaks the code, here is the line of code that breaks. If I attempt to fix the error it will instead run into a type mismatch error

```
Set rcPT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=rcPTCache, TableDestination:=Range("A1"))
```

I am fairly certain it has something to do with the data range as it works when I use a different range but im not sure, it may be a easy fix and I just need another perspective. Here is the full code.

```
 Dim wbReviewPivots As Workbook
Set wbReviewPivots = ActiveWorkbook



Dim wsPivots As Worksheet
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim endCell As Integer
Dim rcPT As PivotTable
Dim rcPTCache As PivotCache
Dim rcPlace As Range



' set variable equal to data sheet and pivot sheet
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("//Workbook\\")
Set wsPivots = wbReviewPivots.Sheets("RootCausesCleaned")
Set wsData = Sheets("RawData") 'gets the last row within the rawdata sheet
endCell = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'set the data range

wsData.Activate
Dim MyRange1 As Range, MyRange2 As Range, dataRange As Range
Set MyRange1 = Range("A1:E" & endCell)
Set MyRange2 = Range("G1:AA" & endCell)
Set dataRange = Application.Union(MyRange1, MyRange2)



'create root cause pivot chart
wbReviewPivots.Sheets("RootCausesCleaned").Activate
Set rcPTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange)
Set rcPT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=rcPTCache, TableDestination:=Range("A1"))

    With rcPT
        .PivotFields("Cause").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Cause (Sub Category)").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Task ID").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
```

The dataRange excludes the G column because if its included another error is run into, Its not a required column so it doesn't matter if the columns excluded but I do think its making it difficult to create the pivot tables.

The excel table object could also be used, but this still runs into the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't create a pivot table from non-contiguous ranges like you're trying to do by excluding column G.
2. Your Type Mismatch error is from trying to declare a `PivotCache` using a `Range` object for `SourceData`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627908/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-when-defining-pivot-cache), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range), shows you how to use a `String` reference.
3. `endCell` should be a `Long`, not an `Integer`. (Just a thought, maybe use `endRow` or some other name, `endCell` sounds like a `Range` variable and might be misleading.)
4. Since `dataRange` is in a different workbook, you can use its `Address` with `External:=True` to get its full `String` reference including the workbook name. I'd use the `xlR1C1` reference style since it sounds like A1-style can cause errors with larger data sets.

So to fix your errors, make these tweaks...

```
Dim dataAddress as String
Set dataRange = wsData.Range("A1:AA" & endCell) ' or maybe endRow
dataAddress = dataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True)
```

Then within `Set rcPTCache = ...`, `SourceData:=dataAddress`.