# Unable to use macro for pivot table for more than 65500 rows

Tags: asp.net, vba, excel, pivot

I am Using Macro for pivot table in Excel...

when i am trying to put pivot table for a data of around 80,000 rows my pivot table is not appearing but if i take only 65000 rows than its working can anyone help me in  debugging this error.

These are the VBA Codes that i am using

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")


'Define Data Range

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="EmployeePivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="EmployeePivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("EmployeePivotTable").PivotFields("FilePeriod")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("EmployeePivotTable").PivotFields("ProjectNumber")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("EmployeePivotTable").PivotFields("EffectiveFTE")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
End With

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("EmployeePivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("EmployeePivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't ever use `On Error Resume Next` without error handling. This line just hides all error messages in the whole procedure but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. Remove that line and tell which errors you get and in which line. Otherwise you cannot debug/fix your code.

Comment: I am getting "Type Mismatch" error in these codes                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                       
 'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="EmployeePivotTable")

Comment: I am getting "Type Mismatch" error in these codes

Comment: Instead of using a `Range` object for `SourceData`, use a `String` reference. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627908/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-when-defining-pivot-cache), among others.

Comment: `"Data!R1C1...`, right? I don't think you need the `'`.

Comment: Thanks Man i got it