# VBA pivot table lrow/lcol

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to use lastRow and lastColumn to capture a whole excel table that will pivot to fields I had pre-set. I am not receiving any errors but when I run the code it doesn't auto populate the pivot table. It deletes the old pivot and creates a new one just without the auto population of the fields. What am I missing in my code thats not capturing this? Thank you.

```
Sub MakeAPivotTable()

    Dim pt As pivotTable
    Dim cacheofpt As PivotCache     ' this is the source data for the pt
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim Report As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim DataInsert As Worksheet



    'Sheets("sheet1").Select
    'SummaryTable = Range("B2:E5")

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Reclass_PushBack").TableRange2.Clear   'deletes any previous pivotTable

    ' set the cache of pt

    Set DataInsert = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataInsert")

    With DataInsert
    'Set SummaryTable = Range("A1:E5")
        Set Report = .Cells
        'Last row
        lastRow = Report.Find(What:="*", After:=Report.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        'Last Column
        lastCol = Report.Find(What:="*", After:=Report.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
        Set WholeRng = Range(Cells(9, "A"), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

    End With
       Report.Select
    Set cacheofpt = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SummaryTable)

    'cretae the pivot table
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
     Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(cacheofpt, Range("a1"), "MyPT")

     'put the fields in
     With pt
     'add the fields
    .PivotFields("PO Requester").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Func Currency Amt").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Reason").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Reclass Flag").Orientation = xlDataField

    'go to classic view
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

     End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and see what error(s) you actually get. 2. When creating a pivot cache, use a `String` reference for `SourceData` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range). Right now you're using a `Range` object (`SummaryTable`).

Comment: The questions you referred me to is not using a lastrow/lastcol. How would I implement that with a String reference for SourceData? The excel table will change the amount of rows each month.

Comment: The key is R1C1 notation, which that question uses. In `SourceData:="Data!R1C1:R500000C2`, 500000 is your `lastRow` and 2 is your `lastCol`. So if your source data is on Sheet1, starting in A1, your string would be `"Sheet1!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C" & lastCol`