# Making a Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to make a pivot table that displays various location IDS. I am getting the following error message "application - defined or object defined error" at line Set pc:

I am not sure what is wrong ,and any guidance would be helpful

Sub createpivot()

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim PRange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet
Dim Psheet As Worksheet



Set Psheet = Worksheets("Pivot Table")
Set Dsheet = Worksheets("Locations")

lastrow = Dsheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Dsheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = Dsheet.Cells(8, 21).Resize(lastrow, lastcol)
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(5, 5), TableName:="Locations Month over Month")
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(5, 5), TableName:="Locations Month over Month")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Locations Month over Month").PivotFields("Location IDs")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1`enter code here`
```

Comment: Is it a typo or do you actually have `.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(5, 5), TableName:="Locations Month over Month")` on the end of the `Set pc = ...` line?

Comment: While you're at it, it's best practice to use a `String` reference for `SourceData`, not a `Range` object like `PRange`, when creating a pivot cache. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range) or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel)

Comment: not a typo, should i remove it? @BigBen

Comment: Absolutely - it's duplicated from the line beneath it.