# How to overcome the 65536 Excel row limit when using win32 in Python and Excel 2010

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I can create an Excel 2010 pivot table using an input worksheet of greater than 65536 rows. When I try this in Python using win32com.client and 'Excel.Application' this fails with the message

```
Exception: Type mismatch.
```

This was still a cryptic message but the fact that 65536 is the sweet spot suggests to me that the the code cannot handle Excel sheet ranges with more than this number of rows.

```
import win32api
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
Excel   = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("output.xlsx")
sh_data = wb.Worksheets("DATA")
cl1 = sh_data.Cells(1,1)
cl2 = sh_data.Cells(65537,6)

PivotSourceRange = sh_data.Range(cl1,cl2)

sh_output = wb.Worksheets("OUTPUT")
outlc=sh_output.Cells(1,1)
PivotTargetRange=  sh_output.Range(outlc,outlc)
PivotTableName = 'ReportPivotTable'
try:
    PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=PivotSourceRange, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)
except pythoncom.com_error as error:
    print(error)
    print("Exception: " + win32api.FormatMessage(error.excepinfo[5]))
```

This is not a complete code snippet and the code fails at the PivotCache line with:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352571), 3)
Exception: Type mismatch.
```

Can I force it to treat the output.xlsx file as an Excel 2010 file to overcome this problem? Excel 2010 is the only version of Excel on my computer.

Thank you.

Comment: Best to pass SourceData a String representing the address, not a range object. From the `PivotCaches.Create` VBA [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create): "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly."

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range